# What does 'main()' does in the if statement here?

Tags: c

*This is a code for printing numbers from 1 to 10 without using semicolons. I tried execeting this without the main() in the if statement but it seems to be not working as intended.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int N = 10;

int main()
{
    static int x  = 1;
    if( printf("%d", x) && x++ < N && main())   //   <--  THIS LINE
        return 0;
}
```

*I dont get whats the point of && main()) here
when i remove it, it prints only 1, but when i have it it prints values 1 to 10.

Comment: @Raildex it's not.

Comment: @Raildex In C++ yes, not in C.

Comment: @hmmmMm I did some reformatting your code to make it a little bit clearer. What `main()` does is simply call the function `main` recursively, and using its return value as part of the condition (`main` will always return `0` though). It's bad code, and not something you should use to learn anything useful from.

Comment: *means without using ' ; '* - but current code uses 3 of those

Comment: [No semicolons in *code* at all](https://godbolt.org/z/WWYfcW3dW) ;)

Answer (score 1):

While this code is written with readability very much ignored, but it just calls `main()` recursively until `x` (which is static so it's a global even though it's defined in a function) is equal to `N`.

Written in a more explicit and classic manner,

```c
printf("%d", x);
if (x++ < N) {
    main();
}
```

or in an even more explicit manner, avoiding the post-increment:

```c
printf("%d", x);
if (x < N) {
    x += 1;
    main();
}
```

Comment: (+1) Might want to add that the code in the question relies on the short-circuit evaluation of boolean operators  (here: `&&`), and that `printf()` actually returns an `int` (here: non-zero).